# How to close a book in Apple Books app in iPadOS 17?

Tags: ipad, books, ipados

In iPadOS 17, I seem to be stuck inside an open book. I cannot find a way to close a book. I want to return to my list of books, and the book store, etc.

When I tap in the middle of the screen, I get a small notice at the top telling me my percentage through this open book. And I  get a small icon in the lower right corner that when tapped offers font settings. But I cannot find a way to exit the current book.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the single-page mode, either:

- Drag from the center of the screen downward.  You will see the page animate into shrinking.
- Tap the middle of the screen. Then tap the teeny-tiny ❎ button appearing in upper-right corner of the page.

If in scrolling-page mode:

- Tap the middle of the screen. Then tap the teeny-tiny ❎ button appearing in upper-right corner of the page.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce both the issue and the solution. When I click about somewhere in the middle of the page, you have a bar popping at the top with options such as "Annotate" or "Search" but also a button like this: "<" to go back to close the book.